# How to select multi select box chzn-select-deselect automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I have a multiselect chzn-select-deselect box. I want to select multiple values at once when I select a particular value. I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="filter_list_dropdwn" class="inp direct_value_opp fl" multiple="multiple" name="data[value1][]">
       <option value="1" parent_id="0"> parent1</option>
       <option value="2" parent_id="1"> child1 of parent1</option>
       <option value="3" parent_id="1"> child2 of parent1</option>
       <option value="4" parent_id="3"> child of child3</option>
</select>
```

If I select parent1 then automatically it's child will be selected. The working script is this:

```
    $('#filter_list_dropdwn option:not(:selected)').live('click', function () {
        unselected = $(this);

        var parent_id = $(unselected).attr("value");
        $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[parent_id=' + parent_id + ']').each(function (i, selected) {
            $(this).prop('selected', false).click();
        });
    });

    $('#filter_list_dropdwn option:selected').live('click', function () {
        selected = $(this);
        var parent_id = $(selected).attr("value");
        $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[parent_id=' + parent_id + ']').each(function (i, selected) {
            $(this).prop('selected', true).click();
        });
    });
```

Here is the fiddle for the above functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/NEXv3/

Now, I wanted to apply the same in `chzn-select-deselect` option. So, I modified the script like this:

```
$('#filter_list_dropdwn option:not(:selected)').live('click', function () {
    unselected = $(this);

    var parent_id = $(unselected).attr("value");
    $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[parent_id=' + parent_id + ']').each(function (i, selected) {
        $(this).attr('selected', false).chosen();
    });
});

$('#filter_list_dropdwn option:selected').live('click', function () {
    selected = $(this);
    var parent_id = $(selected).attr("value");
    $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[parent_id=' + parent_id + ']').each(function (i, selected) {
        $(this).attr('selected', true).chosen();
    });
});
```

But it didn't work as expected. Can anyone suggest me what went wrong in applying the same automatic multi select option in `chzn-select-deselect` dropdown?

Comment: `parent_id` is not a correct attribute. Use `data-parentid` i.e. and use `$(element).data('parentid')`. Also, consider no longer using `live` but `on` with event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick look at the [author website](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), you will see that you have the following event when the selection changes :

```
$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );
```

And to update the select dropdown, you have to do :

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Now, your code have to be rewrited from the beginning :

```
$('#filter_list_dropdwn').chosen(); // to apply the plugin

$("#filter_list_dropdwn").chosen().change(function(e, option){
    // when changing, option will contain {selected: "value"} or {deselected: "value"}
    var selected = option.selected;
    var deselected = option.deselected;

    if (selected !== undefined) {
        // if we have selected a new option
        $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[data-parent_id=' + selected + ']').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('selected', true);
        });
    } else if(deselected !== undefined) {
        // if we have deselected an option
        $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[data-parent_id=' + deselected + ']').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('selected', false);
        });
    }
    // redraw the "chosen select" when all changes have been made to the real one
    $("#filter_list_dropdwn").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGfK8/2/)**

**Edit :**

The code can be far shorter :

```
$("#filter_list_dropdwn").chosen().change(function(e, option){
    var parent_id = option.selected !== undefined ? option.selected : option.deselected;

    $('#filter_list_dropdwn option[data-parent_id=' + parent_id + ']').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('selected', option.selected !== undefined ? true : false);
    });

    $("#filter_list_dropdwn").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGfK8/3/)**

**Edit #2 :**

Recursive implementation :

**[Final demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGfK8/4/)**

Comment: I noticed that I ommited the recursive aspect... I'll try to make this working later

Comment: This would be another question, but as you see [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), you'll have to use the `change` event. The event log is quite clear : `change {"val":"2","added":{"id":2,"text":"task"},"removed":{"id":0,"text":"story"}}`